# Syntax error in date calculation

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using following code in Xcode:

```
(void)updateLabel 
{
    NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
    int hour = 23 - [[now dateWithCalendarFormat:nil timeZone:nil] hourOfDay];
    int min = 59 - [[now dateWithCalendarFormat:nil timeZone:nil] minuteOfHour];
    int sec = 59 - [[now dateWithCalendarFormat:nil timeZone:nil] secondOfMinute];
    countdownLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, min,sec];
}
```

And am getting the following error. How can I fix this?

> error: invalid operands to binary - (have 'int' and 'id')

Comment: which line gives your error?

Comment: all three.......in which int is used for hour, min, sec

Comment: I tried same code in my system, it workd good.

Comment: You are doing for ios or mac ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using this way :-

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSHourCalendarUnit  | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger hour = [dateComponents hour];
NSInteger minute = [dateComponents minute];
NSInteger second = [dateComponents second];
[gregorian release];
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
NSDate* now = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:(NSHourCalendarUnit  | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:now];
long hour =23-[dateComponents hour];
long min =59-[dateComponents minute];
long sec =59-[dateComponents second];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld:%02ld:%02ld", hour, min,sec];
NSLog(@"--> %@",str);
```